# Angular form is not able to add text box dynamically when clicking Add button

Tags: angular, dynamic-forms

I have put together a very simple angular form where one button suppose to add text fields dynamically when user clicks on it. I am missing something because when I click "Add" button it does not adds a new text box dynamically. 
Can someone tell me what am I missing,

app-component.ts`

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, FormArray, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  feedbackForm: FormGroup;
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.feedbackForm = this.fb.group({
      goodFeedback: this.fb.array([])
    });
  }

  get goodFeedback() {
    return this.feedbackForm.get('goodFeedback') as FormArray;
  }

  addGoodFeedback() {
    this.goodFeedback.push(this.fb.control(''));
  }
}
```

app-component.html

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <h2>Add Feedback</h2>

  <form [formGroup]="feedbackForm">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Good Feedback</label>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm m-2" (click)="addGoodFeedback()">Add</button>
      <input type="text" formControlName="goodfeedback" class="form-control">

      <div formArrayName="goodfeedback" *ngFor="let goodfeedback of goodfeedback.controls; let i=index">
        <input type="text" class="form-control my-1" [formControlName]="i">
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

I did a Stackblitz that solves your problem: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ntt6qb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

In the view, I just replaced that line `let goodfeedback of goodfeedback.controls` with `let feedback of feedbackForm.get('goodFeedback').controls`.

I think that when you add a control in the `controls` array of the form, Angular doesn't see that the array changed, so when you iterate through your controls with `let goodfeedback of goodfeedback.controls`, it sees that `controls` is empty.

Comment: Thanks! That worked.. I really appreciate your help!

Comment: The functionality is working however I am seeing this error in my console .. any suggestions please?

Comment: ERROR Error: Cannot find control with name: 'goodfeedback'
    at _throwError (forms.js:2144)
    at setUpFormContainer (forms.js:2126)
    at FormGroupDirective.push../node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm5/forms.js.FormGroupDirective.addFormArray (forms.js:5330)
    at FormArrayName.push../node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm5/forms.js.FormArrayName.ngOnInit (forms.js:5570)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:22001)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:23265)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:23227)
    at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:23861)